# Eclipse Memory Analyzer has no response after starting up

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I downloaded a stand-alone Eclipse Memory Analyzer from the official site, intending to use it to open a hprof file to do some analysis work. However, the application seems to get stuck after starting up. I can do nothing but drag the window, as the figure shows below:[image]

The OS I’m using is macOS Sierra, the mat version is 1.6.1, and here is the MemoryAnalyzer.ini:

```
  -startup
    ../Eclipse/plugins/.    org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
-data
/Users/XXX/eclipse_data
--launcher.library
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xmx2g
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XstartOnFirstThread
```

Can anyone give me some advice? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The first two lines of `MemoryAnalyzer.ini` seems to be broken (or maybe copy and paste error). Are you sure you downloaded it from the [official site](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/downloads.php)? The current version is 1.7.0.20170613 (released June 2017).

Comment: @howlger It’s a paste error. I also tried 1.7.0 and got the same result

Comment: Did you mean by _"seems to get stuck after starting up"_ you cannot click on _Workbench_? What about the heap status that is shown in the status bar at the bottom? Does it change or is it also frozen?

Comment: @howlger Exactly. I can’t  click on the workbench, but the heap status increases slowly.

Comment: In the `.ini` file, can you try to add `-clean` as the first line and to change the line after `-data` to `/Users/XXX/eclipse_data_2` (maybe it is caused by your existing workspace)?

Comment: @howlger Do you mean put  `-startup` right under `-clean`?

Comment: Yes, `-clean` as an additional first line. If this and using a new workspace does not help, check the file `/Users/XXX/eclipse_data_2/.metadata/.log`.

Comment: Sadly it’s still not working. I tried both 1.6.1 and 1.7 . There has no `.log` folder but a `.plugins` folder under the `.metadata`.

Comment: `.log` is not a folder, but a file that is created as soon something will be logged. As long as there is activity on the heap status, I would recommend waiting.

Comment: @howlger I have been waiting for about 1 hour but `.log` file still hasn’t shown up. I notice that a new folder is added under the `.plugins` folder, so is it possible that MAT is undergoing the initialization process so it can’t be clicked?

Comment: Yes, most of it has already been initialized. If it is not [this issue](https://www.eclipse.org/org/press-release/20170925criticalbug.php), can you run the _[Eclipse IDE for Java Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/oxygen2)? If yes, does [installing MAT as plug-in](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/memory-analyzer-0) work?

Comment: @howlger The former one can’t work, I will try the latter one later.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using `jdk1.8.0_161.jdk`

Then using an older JVM :

```
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
```

now it's working again.

My complete MemoryAnalyzer.ini:

```
-startup
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
-data 
/Users/German/tmp/workspace_mat
-vmargs
-Xmx5g
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XstartOnFirstThread
```

PD: I haven't tested it with an older jdk8 version. I remember, it used to work with older than version 161.

Comment: Yes, using older version of JVM solves the issue (in my case jdk1.7.0_111.jdk). However, it worked for me after setting it in Info.plist, not in MemoryAnalyzer.ini.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here with High Sierra.

I installed a vanilla Eclipse from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

And then installed MAT through the update-site at: 
http://download.eclipse.org/mat/1.7/update-site/

Once you restart eclipse you can select `Window / Perspective / Open Perspective / Other / Memory Analysis` and you will have a working installation.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem while opening MAT on my machine.
Os Version: MAC Os Siera 10.12.6(16G1212)
Java/JDK : jdk-9.0.1.jdk

Somehow it was not reading default Java_home location. I have added Java_home location to the info.plist and it worked.
`<string>-vm</string><string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home</string>`

`<array>
<string>-vm</string><string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home</string>
            <!-- to use a specific Java version (instead of the platform's default) uncomment one of the following options,
                    or add a VM found via $/usr/libexec/java_home -V
                <string>-vm</string><string>/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Commands/java</string>
                <string>-vm</string><string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java</string>
            -->
            <string>-keyring</string>
      <string>~/.eclipse_keyring</string>
            <string>-showlocation</string>
        </array>`